# Is this possible to require website visitor to fan a facebook page to access content on the website?

Tags: facebook, web, token, require

I was wonder if this would be possible and how to do it.  I have a personal website. I wanted to have it so that in order for the visitor to gain access to a specific page,the website checks to see if that visitor is a fan of our page on facebook. If they are not, they must become one to advance to the page content on my website.  I thought perhaps there is a code that would do this? Maybe some kind of token/cookie combo?  Any help would be great. Iv been searching for a solution to this.  The page on my personal site gets a lot of traffic so I want to require all visitors to that page to become a facebook fan and the site verifies this before letting them into the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of Facebook you can only check if a user likes your page if you have the user login to your site first.

So you’d need to set up an app, have the user login, ask for their permission to read their likes, read the info if they like your particular page – and then either let them see the content, or present them with a like button.

How it’s done in detail is all in the docs – so please have a look around there if you think it’s worth the cost.